# Почему мне всегда выдаёт YES

Tags: python

Дана задача:
Заданы две клетки шахматной доски. Если они покрашены в один цвет, то выведите слово YES, а если в разные цвета — то NO. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки.
Я сделал код, который по моему мнению должен был работать, но он всегда выдаёт YES. Что не так?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
if a == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7:
    if c == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: А просто `(a+b-c-d)%2` посчитать не проще?

Answer (score 1):

Это потому что `a == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7` всегда `true` и `c == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7` всегда `true`.

`a == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7` всегда `true`, потому что 3 всегда true.

`c == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 and b == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7` всегда `true`, потому что 3 всегда true.